# Inspiration for Nirrti of SG-1 in Doctor Who?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

The character [Nirrti in Stargate SG-1](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Nirrti) draws inspiration for her name and costume from Hindu scripture, but as a Goa'uld, her character seems something else entirely. I was just reading about a Doctor Who character known as [The Rani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rani_(Doctor_Who)) (I probably saw the episodes in which she appeared, but too long ago to remember them) and found what appears to be an interesting parallel. Each is something of a supervillain in their franchise, engaged quite specifically in biological experimentation for nefarious purpose. Did the SG-1 writers draw on the Doctor Who legacy for inspiration when they created the character Nirrti?

Comment: More likely a female Dr. Mengele

Comment: Unlikely. Just parallel thinking.